# In Python 3, how can I convert ascii to string, *without encoding/decoding*

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.6

I converted a string from utf8 to this:

b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe6\xb2\xa1\xe6\x9c\x89\xe7\x94\xb5@xn--ssdcsrs-2e1xt16k.com.au'

I now want that chunk of ascii back into string form, so there is no longer the little b for bytes at the beginning.

BUT I don't want it converted back to UTF8, I want that same sequence of characters that you ses above in my Python string.

How can I do so? All I can find are ways of converting bytes to string along with encoding or decoding.

Comment: Still none of the answers is accepted. Is there anything unclear in my answer? Or just forgot to click? I like to have things done and finished, so the future potential visitors see that the question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (wrong) answer is quite simple:

> **chr(asciiCode)**

In your special case:

```
myString = ""
for char in b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe6\xb2\xa1\xe6\x9c\x89\xe7\x94\xb5@xn--ssdcsrs-2e1xt16k.com.au':
    myString+=chr(char)
print(myString)
```

gives:

```
ææ²¡æçµ@xn--ssdcsrs-2e1xt16k.com.au
```

**Maybe you are also interested in the right answer?** It will probably not please you, because it says you have ALWAYS to deal with encoding/decoding ... because `myString` is now both UTF-8 and ASCII at the same time (exactly as it already was before you have "converted" it to ASCII).

*Notice that how `myString` shows up when you print it will depend on the implicit encoding/decoding used by `print`.*

In other words ...

> **there is NO WAY to avoid encoding/decoding**

but there is a way of doing it a not explicit way.

**I suppose that reading my answer provided HERE: [Converting UTF-8 (in literal) to Umlaute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472823/converting-utf-8-in-literal-to-umlaute/43473217#43473217) will help you much in understanding the whole encoding/decoding thing.**

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not ASCII, as it contains for instance the byte `\xe6`, which is higher than 127. It's still UTF8.

The *representation* of the string (with the `'b'` at the start, then a `'`, then a '\', ...), *that* is ASCII. You get it with `repr(yourstring)`. But the contents of the string that you're printing is UTF8.

But I don't think you need to turn that back into an UTF8 string, but it may depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Each individual character is entirely valid to go into a Python string.  How can I get them in there?  Don't think about decoding/encoding.  I don't want it decoded/encoded, I just want each character into my string.

Comment: Well, `s = "b'\\xe6\\x88\\x91\\xe6\\xb2\\xa1\\xe6\\x9c\\x89\\xe7\\x94\\xb5@xn--ssdcsrs-2e1xt16k.com.au'". Is that what you mean? There should be easier ways of achieving what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or `s = r"b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe6\xb2\xa1\xe6\x9c\x89\xe7\x94\xb5@xn--ssdcsrs-2e1xt16k.com.au'"`, note the `r`, that makes it unnecessary to escape the backslashes.

Comment: As you suggest @RemcoGerlich, repr() seem to get me most of the way there, now I just need to strip off the leading b and the surrounding quotes and  have what I am after thankyou.